# Express JS I want to return true in else condition but it's undefinend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to return true value, so I can catch it in React-Native, but when I try to connect to the account with the right values, I get undefined in the console of the back-end

```
login : async function (email, password) {
    try {
        const sqlEmail = "Select * from users where email = ?";
        db.query(sqlEmail, email, async (error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            if(!results || !(await bcryptjs.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
                console.log("tes pas connecté")
                return false;                   
            }  else {
                return true;
            }
        })    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error (error)            
    }        
},
```

and this is my route :

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res)  {
    userController.login(req.body.email, req.body.password)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        res.send(result)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err)
    })
})
```

Thank you

Comment: Your `login` function has no `return` statement. `return true` belongs to the anonymous callback function you pass to `query`.

Comment: Why is `login` marked with the `async` keyword? You aren't `await`ing anything inside it.

Comment: Because i'm in module.exports so I think that I have to use Async function, I'm beginner but I have to return true in the Else statement, how can I do it ?

Comment: There is no requirement that a function be marked as `async` in order to export it. See the duplicate for a discussion of working with asynchronous functions that use callbacks.

Comment: Just a sample answer above response => `login : async function (email, password) {
  let _resolve, _reject;
  const dbQueryPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _resolve = resolve;
    _reject = reject;
  });
  db.query(sqlEmail, email, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      _reject(error);
    }
    const isMatched = await bcryptjs.compare(password, results[0].password);
    if(!results || !isMatched) {
      console.log("tes pas connecté")
      _resolve(true);
    }  else {
      _resolve(false);
    }
  });
  return await dbQueryPromise;
},`

Comment: Thank u for your code, but it tells me that the await before the bcrypt can not be there because its not an async function, how can I resolve it ?

Comment: It's okay, I resolved the problem, thank you very much, here is the good code :